# Angular 2 synchronization issue - call a function after completing 2 async calls

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, synchronization

I have an scenario where I need to call a function C after the functions A and B, which are executed asynchronously. Functions A and B retrieve data from the server which I need later to call function C, but each of them are independent.

I could just chain them, call A then call B after the data is retrieved and finally call C after retrieving the data of B. But since A and B don't rely on each other it makes more sense to run them in parallel and then after both complete run C.

Here some sample code:

```
ngOninit() {
    this.mySrv.getSomeStuff() // Returns an observable
        .subscribe(data => this.stuff = data);
    this.mySrv.getOtherStuff().subscribe(data => this.other = data);
    // I need both data to execute the next function
    this.mySrv.doSomething(this.stuff, this.other)
            .subscribe(data => {/* do something */});
}
```

Comment: Look up `Promise.all` which sounds like what you want based on your description. I could provide more details if you post some sample code demonstrating your problem?

Comment: @CRice I've posted a simple code sample to illustrate the scenario.

Comment: Ahhh good ol' observables. Well in that case I think the `Observable.zip()` static method is what you want. In your case, `Observable.zip(this.mySrv.getSomeStuff(), this.mySrv.getOtherStuff()).subscribe(([stuff, other]) => { /* do something */ })`. See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Observable.forkJoin` for the first two requests, which runs them in parallell. Then using `flatMap` (`mergeMap`) you can execute request based on the previous results and then finally subscribe. So something like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  Observable.forkJoin(this.mySrv.getSomeStuff(), this.mySrv.getOtherStuff())
    .flatMap(data => {
      console.log(data[0]) // result of 'getSomeStuff()'
      console.log(data[1]) // result of 'getOtherStuff()'
      return this.mySrv.doSomething(data[0], data[1])
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data) // result of 'doSomething()'
    })
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `Observable.zip`?

Comment: Sure, you can use `zip` as well here. They are very similar, `forkJoin` waits for all observables to complete then emits the **last** values. But in this case they would behave in the same way, as only one value is returned from each observable.